# How to use 3 cameras simultaneously in Unity

Tags: unity

[image]I'm working on a project that requires 3 panels, each rendering a game object.  There will be a search box and when the player enters a string, that key word will zoom to the tagged location on the each object in the 3 panels. How can I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Can you show us a mock-up of what you want this to look like? (The layout of the 3 panels is relevant to a detailed answer)

Comment: Hey Lionboy, could you provide us with a little more information? Maybe some screenshots of what it looks like now and/or drawings of what you want it to look like/do?
For example: Is the string being entered into a UI input field? Does the key word move independent of what the other cameras are rendering?

Comment: @basklein yes I'm using an input field and will do a string search.  I was thinking of making zoom/translate scripts, then name the scripts like 'eyes.cs', 'foot.cs' etc and then if I search using 'eyes' for example, the string search will then have an event to call eyes.cs script and activate it.  Not even sure my thought process even makes sense at the moment.  Any direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want multiple cameras on multiple screen you need multiple cameras and set their target Display property of camera component on different screens. like this:

```
void Start
{
      Camera.main.targetDisplay = 0;
        camera2.targetDisplay = 1;
}
```

if you want to render camera on different elements like Ui panel or... you can do like this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-targetTexture.html

for that you need to render camera to a **render texture** and set the result on any thing possible

[image]

i wanted to write for you whta to do but this tutorial is complete:

https://blog.theknightsofunity.com/implementing-minimap-unity/

Comment: Thank you so much @virtouso and all who gave feedback.  I believe I have a good start now for my project.

Comment: great to hear that @Lionboy1